# NoUiSlider Tooltip

Tags: jquery, nouislider

Made a Slider using noUislider. How do I hide and show the tooltip?

Here's what I have so far:

```
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
    start: [10],
    connect: "lower",
    tooltips: [wNumb({decimals:0})],
    orientation:"vertical",
    direction:"ltr",
    range: {
        'min': 000,
        'max': 100
    }
});

slider.noUiSlider.on('start', function(){
    ;
});

slider.noUiSlider.on('end', function(){
    ;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

noUiSlider has an update option function

```
updateSlider.noUiSlider.updateOptions({
      tooltips: false
});
```

You could toggle the tooltip option on the respected event

Answer (score 0):

First, find the tooltip: `var tt = slider.querySelector('.noUi-tooltip');`.

Then you can toggle a `hidden` class that you've defined in CSS: (e.g. `.hidden { display: none; }`): `tt.classList.toggle('hidden')`.